# PhantomJS "Terminated" STDERR cause?

Tags: phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS(2.0) to render a screenshot on Ubuntu 14.04. I have a pretty standard script to render a page (https://gist.github.com/Jaciones/b078326a0a6d664a5f30).

Has always worked great.

But now, with a particular website url, it will fail about 1 in 4 times. On the failing ones, it will hang for 60 seconds, and then exit (with no STDOUT), but the STDERR will be "Terminated". What does this mean? Is this PhantomJS crashing, or is this just a "timeout" internally trying to load a webpage? I have code in the in my rendering script to output when resources fail, but STDOUT is empty in the failing case (in the non failing case, everything works as expected).

Comment: I'm also seeing this. It appears to be because the page I'm rendering is very long (1280 x 65871) and this is crashing the render process. It may be running out of memory, or it may be a bug in the underlying implementation that shows up on large images.

Comment: I never found an answer or a solution for this :( We ended up going back to PhantomJS < 2.0 to avoid this problem.